# AndEngine - update handlers

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using the latest version of AndEngine, and I'm wondering Which is better to make several Update Handlers for different things or to make one and calculate the elapsed Time?

```
GameEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.2f, true, new ITimerCallback() { // create new bullet }
GameEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.2f, true, new ITimerCallback() { // create new bonus }
GameEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1f, true, new ITimerCallback() { // create new asteroid }

GameEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.2f, true, new ITimerCallback()
{
    // calculate elapsed time and create objects
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using separate updatehandler. Not for the sake of performance or something but, for the scalablity of the software. I am adapting and updating my code very often. Using separate handler help to do it easily... Adding new objects and more important deleting objects are much easier(in your case bullets or asteroids)...